# Sequence $a_n \searrow 0$ and $\sum a_n < +\infty$ but $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} \in o(a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a positive decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that $a_n \searrow 0$ and $\sum a_n < +\infty$ but $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} \in o(a_n)$ for all $\epsilon>0$?

Motivation: Intuitively, we would think that the harmonic series $\frac{1}{n}$ is the asymptotic 'border' between sequences such that $\sum a_n$ converges and those sequences that don't. This would imply that, roughly speaking, the 'slowest' converging series are of the form $\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ where $\epsilon$ is small.

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log^2(2+n)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual "neat separation" between slowly convergent and slowly divergent series with positive, decreasing terms. By [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) all the following series are divergent
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n},\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\log(1+n)},\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\log(1+n)\log(1+\log(1+n))} $$
and all the following series are convergent:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2},\quad \color{red}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\log^2(1+n)}},\quad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\log(1+n)\log^2(1+\log(1+n))} $$
The red one provides an example fulfilling your constraints.